# Github and scripting daily builds/branches/tags

Tags: git, github

I would like to automate the creation of daily builds of my github project.  Is that possible?  If so, can anyone point me to any resources on how to automate this process?

I've been googling till my head spins, and maybe I'm just asking the wrong thing.  I am hoping this community can please help me with this task.

I am using the Windows platform.

Thank you

Comment: What do u want to automate, build on push, daily build or something else?

Comment: I really just want to automate the backing up of the code daily.  I'm just not sure how to go about this.

Comment: U dont trust github for that?

Comment: It's more a code protection thing and for testing.  Daily builds are needed for others to test.  Instead of pulling from the main branch, I want to have a way to pull from a daily one.  So at 12:01 AM the build is locked, packaged and able to be done what need to be done.  Not all people live in the same time zone, and I'm just looking for a way to do this.  So I'm trying to make my life easier for the team I'm on.

Comment: You should add this info to your question.

Comment: For the answer, you can create daily tags... if thats what you want...

Comment: Yes, that is what I want, so how do you do this?  Can it be done in a batch file?

Comment: Check [git-tag documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) and yes you can use that in a batch file on command line. And then maybe a scheduler...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to build your project automatically, there is a free website that will do that for you. Its called "travis-ci": https://travis-ci.org/